# Localization of OSX service menu entry does not work for Simplified Chinese

Tags: macos, localization, chinese-locale

I developed an OSX service using Automator, and installed the workflow for all users in */Library/Services*.
The workflow packet contains a folder *Contents*, and within it the file *Info.plist* and a folder *Resources*.
*Resources* contains for every localization a folder with the language code as name, and *lproj* as extension.
Each of these folders contains a strings file *ServiceMenu.strings*.

*Info.plist* contains among others the default menu item title (in my example : "New entry in contacts").
[image]
Every *ServiceMenu.string*s file contains the localization of this default title. In the example for Spanish and Simplified Chinese.
[image]
[image]
**The problem** is that the default title, as well as the localizations in German & Spanish do work, but the localization in Simplified Chinese does not:

When I set in my Mac in *Settings/Preferred Languages* to English, German, or Spanish as the 1st language and re-boot, the service menu entry is correctly displayed in this language.
But when I set Simplified Chinese as the 1st preferred language and re-boot, the menu entry is not displayed in Simplified Chinese, but in the language set as the 1st preferred language **before** the re-boot.

Obviously, the problem is not that the localization is not found - in this case, the default menu entry in *Info.plist* should be shown, but not the entry in the language set before re-boot.

This seems to me to be a OS-X bug. It behaves the same in Mavericks & Yosemite.
Any idea what I could do?

Comment: I must say, I am tired of writing bug reports to Apple. 
After TSI confirmed that this is an OSX bug, I wrote a bug report (# 19169892), and I got 4 weeks later the answer „This issue behaves as intended.“, and a half year later „Please verify this issue in the latest pre-release seed of OS X El Capitan 10.11.“
My answer was „Is it a bug or "intended behavior"?
If it is intended behavior, it does not make sense to test it on El Capitan.
If it is a bug, why was it not fixed?
And eventually, why don't you test it by yourself?“

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I submitted a *Technical Support Incident* (TSI) to Apple and received the answer that this is an OS X bug (I will file a bug report).
A workaround is to name the respective folder not "**zh-Hans.lproj**" as the standard requests, but  "**zh_CN.lproj**" instead.
With this name the menu entry appears correctly in Simplified Chinese.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was going nuts trying to track down why all the other languages worked for me except Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese.  BTW when OS X can't localize the menu in the primary language, it checks the next (i.e., the second) language configured in the system preferences (so it is was not related to the preferred language before the reboot -- it just appeared that way).  Anyway,  thanks again!